# dynamic windows partition install ubuntu dual-os

Tags: dual-boot, windows

Is there problem installing ubuntu along with windows if the partitions are dynamic. I encountered a problem while installing ubuntu. windows partion were not detected while choose optin something else for install.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic partitions is a windows propriety format.  You can't install Ubuntu on a dynamic partition.  You will have to convert your drive to a  basic disk for your Ubuntu installation.

The easiest way I can recommend is to backup the drive, then re-partition is as basic.

There are tools which might provide converting the from dynamic to basic without formating (discussed [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2185662&p=12837853#post12837853))